Previous and Next button with flexbox, how to place them at the left and the right respectively?
I am trying to build a simple pagination system where the user can click on a Next/Prev button to navigate to the next/previous page. I want to place the buttons to the left of the screen and to the right respectively and I did that with flexbox by using justify-content: space-between.
It works fine when the two buttons are displayed but I am using some PHP logic to conditionally display them based on the ability to navigate to the previous or the next page. For instance, on the 1st page, one can't navigate to a previous page so  I don't the Prev button to be present. And that's where the problem appears : if the Prev button is absent, the Next button is placed on the left.
What can I do to keep the Next button to the right even if the Prev button is absent?


div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a.a{
  background: #88f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

/*a.a:nth-child(1){
  display: none;
}*/
<div>
<a class="a">Prev</a>
<a class="a">Next</a>
</div>



The PHP logic is very simple, it looks like this :
<?php if($no_pages_left):?>
<a class="a">Prev</a>
<?php endif ?>
<?php if($no_pages_right):?>
<a class="a">Next</a>
<?php endif ?>


:nth-child(2 of .a) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

will fix it, automatically expanding the element's left margin as much as possible.


div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 50px; /* for demo */
}

a.a {
  background: #88f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

 :nth-child(2 of .a) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

a.a:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
<div>
  <a class="a">Prev</a>
  <a class="a">Next</a>
</div>




Thank you. For some reason the snippet doesn't work tho. But I tried it on codepen and it works. Thanks

It was a mistake in the snippet I think. I replaced :nth-child(2 of .a) with .a:nth-child(2).

No it's not a mistake, it specifically targets the 2nd element that has a class of .a. If the element is not the 2nd child, which it probably won't be then nth-child(2) won't work.

https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYKpPEd

Yeah. Using nth-child(2) was dumb since when the prev button is not rendered then the next button is not the second child anymore, I only noticed it when I implemented it in my project. The best solution I could think of is targeting the button specifically with an id. I tried using nth-child(2 of .a) in Codepen and it didn't work. I don't know why.

div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.a {
  background: #28b2ed;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

<div>
  <a class="a">Prev</a>
  <a class="a">Next</a>
</div>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
